# Problem running npm install - newbie here

Tags: npm, npm-install, nft

As soon as I opened the vs and tried to do the NPM Install as explained in the video im watching... this what happened below:
Obs: I will remove the links cause here it doesnt allow me...

npm WARN old lockfile
npm WARN old lockfile The package-lock.json file was created with an old version of npm,
npm WARN old lockfile so supplemental metadata must be fetched from the registry.
npm WARN old lockfile
npm WARN old lockfile This is a one-time fix-up, please be patient...
npm WARN old lockfile
npm ERR! code 1
npm ERR! path /Users/gus/Library/CloudStorage/OneDrive-Personal/Crypto/Creating NFT/Hashlips/hashlips_art_engine-1.1.2_patch_v6/node_modules/canvas
npm ERR! command failed
npm ERR! command sh -c node-pre-gyp install --fallback-to-build
npm ERR! Failed to execute '/usr/local/bin/node /usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js configure --fallback-to-build --module=/Users/gus/Library/CloudStorage/OneDrive-Personal/Crypto/Creating NFT/Hashlips/hashlips_art_engine-1.1.2_patch_v6/node_modules/canvas/build/Release/canvas.node --module_name=canvas --module_path=/Users/gus/Library/CloudStorage/OneDrive-Personal/Crypto/Creating NFT/Hashlips/hashlips_art_engine-1.1.2_patch_v6/node_modules/canvas/build/Release --napi_version=8 --node_abi_napi=napi --napi_build_version=0 --node_napi_label=node-v93' (1)
npm ERR! node-pre-gyp info it worked if it ends with ok
npm ERR! node-pre-gyp info using node-pre-gyp@1.0.6
npm ERR! node-pre-gyp info using node@16.14.0 | darwin | arm64
npm ERR! node-pre-gyp info check checked for "/Users/gus/Library/CloudStorage/OneDrive-Personal/Crypto/Creating NFT/Hashlips/hashlips_art_engine-1.1.2_patch_v6/node_modules/canvas/build/Release/canvas.node" (not found)
npm ERR! node-pre-gyp http GET ttps://github.com/Automattic/node-canvas/releases/download/v2.8.0/canvas-v2.8.0-node-v93-darwin-unknown-arm64.tar.gz
npm ERR! node-pre-gyp ERR! install response status 404 Not Found on ttps://github.com/Automattic/node-canvas/releases/download/v2.8.0/canvas-v2.8.0-node-v93-darwin-unknown-arm64.tar.gz
npm ERR! node-pre-gyp WARN Pre-built binaries not installable for canvas@2.8.0 and node@16.14.0 (node-v93 ABI, unknown) (falling back to source compile with node-gyp)
npm ERR! node-pre-gyp WARN Hit error response status 404 Not Found on ttps://github.com/Automattic/node-canvas/releases/download/v2.8.0/canvas-v2.8.0-node-v93-darwin-unknown-arm64.tar.gz
npm ERR! gyp info it worked if it ends with ok
npm ERR! gyp info using node-gyp@8.4.1
npm ERR! gyp info using node@16.14.0 | darwin | arm64
npm ERR! gyp info ok
npm ERR! gyp info it worked if it ends with ok
npm ERR! gyp info using node-gyp@8.4.1
npm ERR! gyp info using node@16.14.0 | darwin | arm64
npm ERR! gyp info find Python using Python version 3.8.9 found at "/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/python3"
npm ERR! gyp http GET ttps://nodejs.org/download/release/v16.14.0/node-v16.14.0-headers.tar.gz
npm ERR! gyp http 200 ttps://nodejs.org/download/release/v16.14.0/node-v16.14.0-headers.tar.gz
npm ERR! gyp http GET ttps://nodejs.org/download/release/v16.14.0/SHASUMS256.txt
npm ERR! gyp http 200 ttps://nodejs.org/download/release/v16.14.0/SHASUMS256.txt
npm ERR! gyp info spawn /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/python3
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args [
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/gyp/gyp_main.py',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   'binding.gyp',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-f',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   'make',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-I',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '/Users/gus/Library/CloudStorage/OneDrive-Personal/Crypto/Creating NFT/Hashlips/hashlips_art_engine-1.1.2_patch_v6/node_modules/canvas/build/config.gypi',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-I',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/addon.gypi',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-I',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '/Users/gus/Library/Caches/node-gyp/16.14.0/include/node/common.gypi',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-Dlibrary=shared_library',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-Dvisibility=default',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-Dnode_root_dir=/Users/gus/Library/Caches/node-gyp/16.14.0',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-Dnode_gyp_dir=/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-Dnode_lib_file=/Users/gus/Library/Caches/node-gyp/16.14.0/<(target_arch)/node.lib',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-Dmodule_root_dir=/Users/gus/Library/CloudStorage/OneDrive-Personal/Crypto/Creating NFT/Hashlips/hashlips_art_engine-1.1.2_patch_v6/node_modules/canvas',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-Dnode_engine=v8',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '--depth=.',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '--no-parallel',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '--generator-output',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   'build',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-Goutput_dir=.'
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args ]
npm ERR! /bin/sh: pkg-config: command not found
npm ERR! gyp: Call to 'pkg-config pixman-1 --libs' returned exit status 127 while in binding.gyp. while trying to load binding.gyp
npm ERR! gyp ERR! configure error
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack Error: `gyp` failed with exit code: 1
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.onCpExit (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/lib/configure.js:259:16)
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (node:events:520:28)
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (node:internal/child_process:291:12)
npm ERR! gyp ERR! System Darwin 21.3.0
npm ERR! gyp ERR! command "/usr/local/bin/node" "/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js" "configure" "--fallback-to-build" "--module=/Users/gus/Library/CloudStorage/OneDrive-Personal/Crypto/Creating NFT/Hashlips/hashlips_art_engine-1.1.2_patch_v6/node_modules/canvas/build/Release/canvas.node" "--module_name=canvas" "--module_path=/Users/gus/Library/CloudStorage/OneDrive-Personal/Crypto/Creating NFT/Hashlips/hashlips_art_engine-1.1.2_patch_v6/node_modules/canvas/build/Release" "--napi_version=8" "--node_abi_napi=napi" "--napi_build_version=0" "--node_napi_label=node-v93"
npm ERR! gyp ERR! cwd /Users/gus/Library/CloudStorage/OneDrive-Personal/Crypto/Creating NFT/Hashlips/hashlips_art_engine-1.1.2_patch_v6/node_modules/canvas
npm ERR! gyp ERR! node -v v16.14.0
npm ERR! gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v8.4.1
npm ERR! gyp ERR! not ok
npm ERR! node-pre-gyp ERR! build error
npm ERR! node-pre-gyp ERR! stack Error: Failed to execute '/usr/local/bin/node /usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js configure --fallback-to-build --module=/Users/gus/Library/CloudStorage/OneDrive-Personal/Crypto/Creating NFT/Hashlips/hashlips_art_engine-1.1.2_patch_v6/node_modules/canvas/build/Release/canvas.node --module_name=canvas --module_path=/Users/gus/Library/CloudStorage/OneDrive-Personal/Crypto/Creating NFT/Hashlips/hashlips_art_engine-1.1.2_patch_v6/node_modules/canvas/build/Release --napi_version=8 --node_abi_napi=napi --napi_build_version=0 --node_napi_label=node-v93' (1)
npm ERR! node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess. (/Users/gus/Library/CloudStorage/OneDrive-Personal/Crypto/Creating NFT/Hashlips/hashlips_art_engine-1.1.2_patch_v6/node_modules/@mapbox/node-pre-gyp/lib/util/compile.js:89:23)
npm ERR! node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (node:events:520:28)
npm ERR! node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at maybeClose (node:internal/child_process:1092:16)
npm ERR! node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (node:internal/child_process:302:5)
npm ERR! node-pre-gyp ERR! System Darwin 21.3.0
npm ERR! node-pre-gyp ERR! command "/usr/local/bin/node" "/Users/gus/Library/CloudStorage/OneDrive-Personal/Crypto/Creating NFT/Hashlips/hashlips_art_engine-1.1.2_patch_v6/node_modules/.bin/node-pre-gyp" "install" "--fallback-to-build"
npm ERR! node-pre-gyp ERR! cwd /Users/gus/Library/CloudStorage/OneDrive-Personal/Crypto/Creating NFT/Hashlips/hashlips_art_engine-1.1.2_patch_v6/node_modules/canvas
npm ERR! node-pre-gyp ERR! node -v v16.14.0
npm ERR! node-pre-gyp ERR! node-pre-gyp -v v1.0.6
npm ERR! node-pre-gyp ERR! not ok

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /Users/gus/.npm/_logs/2022-03-04T14_30_24_808Z-debug-0.log
gus@Guss-MacBook-Pro hashlips_art_engine-1.1.2_patch_v6 % npm install
npm WARN old lockfile
npm WARN old lockfile The package-lock.json file was created with an old version of npm,
npm WARN old lockfile so supplemental metadata must be fetched from the registry.
npm WARN old lockfile
npm WARN old lockfile This is a one-time fix-up, please be patient...
npm WARN old lockfile
npm ERR! code 1
npm ERR! path /Users/gus/Library/CloudStorage/OneDrive-Personal/Crypto/Creating NFT/Hashlips/hashlips_art_engine-1.1.2_patch_v6/node_modules/canvas
npm ERR! command failed
npm ERR! command sh -c node-pre-gyp install --fallback-to-build
npm ERR! Failed to execute '/usr/local/bin/node /usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js configure --fallback-to-build --module=/Users/gus/Library/CloudStorage/OneDrive-Personal/Crypto/Creating NFT/Hashlips/hashlips_art_engine-1.1.2_patch_v6/node_modules/canvas/build/Release/canvas.node --module_name=canvas --module_path=/Users/gus/Library/CloudStorage/OneDrive-Personal/Crypto/Creating NFT/Hashlips/hashlips_art_engine-1.1.2_patch_v6/node_modules/canvas/build/Release --napi_version=8 --node_abi_napi=napi --napi_build_version=0 --node_napi_label=node-v93' (1)
npm ERR! node-pre-gyp info it worked if it ends with ok
npm ERR! node-pre-gyp info using node-pre-gyp@1.0.6
npm ERR! node-pre-gyp info using node@16.14.0 | darwin | arm64
npm ERR! node-pre-gyp info check checked for "/Users/gus/Library/CloudStorage/OneDrive-Personal/Crypto/Creating NFT/Hashlips/hashlips_art_engine-1.1.2_patch_v6/node_modules/canvas/build/Release/canvas.node" (not found)
npm ERR! node-pre-gyp http GET https://github.com/Automattic/node-canvas/releases/download/v2.8.0/canvas-v2.8.0-node-v93-darwin-unknown-arm64.tar.gz
npm ERR! node-pre-gyp ERR! install response status 404 Not Found on ttps://github.com/Automattic/node-canvas/releases/download/v2.8.0/canvas-v2.8.0-node-v93-darwin-unknown-arm64.tar.gz
npm ERR! node-pre-gyp WARN Pre-built binaries not installable for canvas@2.8.0 and node@16.14.0 (node-v93 ABI, unknown) (falling back to source compile with node-gyp)
npm ERR! node-pre-gyp WARN Hit error response status 404 Not Found on ttps://github.com/Automattic/node-canvas/releases/download/v2.8.0/canvas-v2.8.0-node-v93-darwin-unknown-arm64.tar.gz
npm ERR! gyp info it worked if it ends with ok
npm ERR! gyp info using node-gyp@8.4.1
npm ERR! gyp info using node@16.14.0 | darwin | arm64
npm ERR! gyp info ok
npm ERR! gyp info it worked if it ends with ok
npm ERR! gyp info using node-gyp@8.4.1
npm ERR! gyp info using node@16.14.0 | darwin | arm64
npm ERR! gyp info find Python using Python version 3.8.9 found at "/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/python3"
npm ERR! gyp info spawn /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/python3
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args [
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/gyp/gyp_main.py',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   'binding.gyp',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-f',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   'make',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-I',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '/Users/gus/Library/CloudStorage/OneDrive-Personal/Crypto/Creating NFT/Hashlips/hashlips_art_engine-1.1.2_patch_v6/node_modules/canvas/build/config.gypi',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-I',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/addon.gypi',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-I',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '/Users/gus/Library/Caches/node-gyp/16.14.0/include/node/common.gypi',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-Dlibrary=shared_library',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-Dvisibility=default',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-Dnode_root_dir=/Users/gus/Library/Caches/node-gyp/16.14.0',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-Dnode_gyp_dir=/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-Dnode_lib_file=/Users/gus/Library/Caches/node-gyp/16.14.0/<(target_arch)/node.lib',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-Dmodule_root_dir=/Users/gus/Library/CloudStorage/OneDrive-Personal/Crypto/Creating NFT/Hashlips/hashlips_art_engine-1.1.2_patch_v6/node_modules/canvas',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-Dnode_engine=v8',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '--depth=.',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '--no-parallel',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '--generator-output',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   'build',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-Goutput_dir=.'
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args ]
npm ERR! /bin/sh: pkg-config: command not found
npm ERR! gyp: Call to 'pkg-config pixman-1 --libs' returned exit status 127 while in binding.gyp. while trying to load binding.gyp
npm ERR! gyp ERR! configure error
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack Error: `gyp` failed with exit code: 1
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.onCpExit (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/lib/configure.js:259:16)
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (node:events:520:28)
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (node:internal/child_process:291:12)
npm ERR! gyp ERR! System Darwin 21.3.0
npm ERR! gyp ERR! command "/usr/local/bin/node" "/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js" "configure" "--fallback-to-build" "--module=/Users/gus/Library/CloudStorage/OneDrive-Personal/Crypto/Creating NFT/Hashlips/hashlips_art_engine-1.1.2_patch_v6/node_modules/canvas/build/Release/canvas.node" "--module_name=canvas" "--module_path=/Users/gus/Library/CloudStorage/OneDrive-Personal/Crypto/Creating NFT/Hashlips/hashlips_art_engine-1.1.2_patch_v6/node_modules/canvas/build/Release" "--napi_version=8" "--node_abi_napi=napi" "--napi_build_version=0" "--node_napi_label=node-v93"
npm ERR! gyp ERR! cwd /Users/gus/Library/CloudStorage/OneDrive-Personal/Crypto/Creating NFT/Hashlips/hashlips_art_engine-1.1.2_patch_v6/node_modules/canvas
npm ERR! gyp ERR! node -v v16.14.0
npm ERR! gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v8.4.1
npm ERR! gyp ERR! not ok
npm ERR! node-pre-gyp ERR! build error
npm ERR! node-pre-gyp ERR! stack Error: Failed to execute '/usr/local/bin/node /usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js configure --fallback-to-build --module=/Users/gus/Library/CloudStorage/OneDrive-Personal/Crypto/Creating NFT/Hashlips/hashlips_art_engine-1.1.2_patch_v6/node_modules/canvas/build/Release/canvas.node --module_name=canvas --module_path=/Users/gus/Library/CloudStorage/OneDrive-Personal/Crypto/Creating NFT/Hashlips/hashlips_art_engine-1.1.2_patch_v6/node_modules/canvas/build/Release --napi_version=8 --node_abi_napi=napi --napi_build_version=0 --node_napi_label=node-v93' (1)
npm ERR! node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess. (/Users/gus/Library/CloudStorage/OneDrive-Personal/Crypto/Creating NFT/Hashlips/hashlips_art_engine-1.1.2_patch_v6/node_modules/@mapbox/node-pre-gyp/lib/util/compile.js:89:23)
npm ERR! node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (node:events:520:28)
npm ERR! node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at maybeClose (node:internal/child_process:1092:16)
npm ERR! node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (node:internal/child_process:302:5)
npm ERR! node-pre-gyp ERR! System Darwin 21.3.0
npm ERR! node-pre-gyp ERR! command "/usr/local/bin/node" "/Users/gus/Library/CloudStorage/OneDrive-Personal/Crypto/Creating NFT/Hashlips/hashlips_art_engine-1.1.2_patch_v6/node_modules/.bin/node-pre-gyp" "install" "--fallback-to-build"
npm ERR! node-pre-gyp ERR! cwd /Users/gus/Library/CloudStorage/OneDrive-Personal/Crypto/Creating NFT/Hashlips/hashlips_art_engine-1.1.2_patch_v6/node_modules/canvas
npm ERR! node-pre-gyp ERR! node -v v16.14.0
npm ERR! node-pre-gyp ERR! node-pre-gyp -v v1.0.6
npm ERR! node-pre-gyp ERR! not ok

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /Users/gus/.npm/_logs/2022-03-04T14_34_08_524Z-debug-0.log

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. Please read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) before asking questions. Also read [How do I ask a question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 3):

I'll try to answer your question

1. Old lock file means you are using newer version of node js

- Try downgrading ( at the time of this writing hashlips seems to be using node 14)

2. Try install canvas manually, because "prebuilds" are not supported for M1 Macs as far as I understand

- https://github.com/Automattic/node-canvas/wiki/Installation%3A-Mac-OS-X

a. "brew install pkg-config cairo pango libpng jpeg giflib librsvg"
b. "npm install canvas" //Inside hashlips directory

After that everything should work

Comment: This worked, and after spending a few hours on it, your solution finally worked!