# pkg-config not found issue on macOS M1

Tags: pkg-config

I think I have tried most of the solutions/suggestions on internet for this issue. 
I'm using macOS Monterey / M1 Max / node version 10., and facing this error saying :

> /bin/sh: 1: pkg-config: not found
> gyp: Call to 'pkg-config pixman-1 --libs' returned exit status 127 while in binding.gyp. while trying to load binding.gyp
>
> Error: `gyp` failed with exit code: 1

I have tried installing pkg-config with brew, but having the same error. 
Does anyone have idea about this issue? I also have rosetta installed.

Answer (score 5):

Answer suggested here worked for me: [Problem running npm install - newbie here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71353070/problem-running-npm-install-newbie-here)

```
brew install pkg-config cairo pango libpng jpeg giflib librsvg
npm install -g canvas
```

Comment: What does it means cairo?

Comment: More information about cairo may be found here: https://formulae.brew.sh/formula/cairo